# and.callthrough returns empty array

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing

I am running unit test on angular app.I see that variable initialized through unit test prints empty array when I log to screen.

```
console.log(component.records);//prints empty array[ ]
console.log(mockReturns['data']['Records']);//prints entire array
```

Unit test

```
//Intialization
let mockReturns={
    data:

    {
      Customer:{
        "CustomerName": "Stress_Test",
      },
      Products:[],
      Records:
      [
        {
          "ActivationId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
       "ActivationState": "Deployed",
          "Address": "",
      "AllowPortalLogin": "Yes",
     },
         ....
       ]
     }//close data
}//overall object

    component.records=mockReturns['data']['Records'];
    component.headers=mockheaders;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let spyOnProductsTable=spyOn(component,'getData').and.callThrough();
    component.getData();
    fixture.detectChanges();




component.ts

 this.records = res['data']['Records'] as Array<any>;
```

Comment: formatted code block

Comment: Thank you,I just interchanged the line  component.records=mockReturns['data']['Records']; after  component.getData(); it works!!!